# Visual Basic Document Reading/Adding to Array

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to read a document and then add it to a string, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function docReader()

    Dim xRead As StreamReader
    Dim i = 0
    xRead = File.OpenText("C:\Users\tbalestra\Desktop\Tickers.txt")
    Do Until xRead.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = xRead.ReadLine
        Dim sec() As String = line.Split("|")
        listQuotes(i) = sec(1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function DocReader() As String()
    Dim listQuotes As New List(Of String)
    Dim xRead As New StreamReader("C:\Users\tbalestra\Desktop\Tickers.txt")

    Do Until xRead.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = xRead.ReadLine
        Dim sec() As String = line.Split("|")
        If (sec.Length > 1) Then
            listQuotes.Add(sec(1))
        End If
    Loop
    Return listQuotes.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: If works, please accept it as answer. Up/Vote too is appreciated.